# Unable to have the author name in the report PDF using the NIPS 2015 LaTeX template

Tags: tex

I am using the nips 2015 template to write a report. I am unable to have the generated PDF reflect the authors’ names. It just says Anonymous.

I am using LaTeX workshop on a windows PC. PS: Overleaf also has the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uncomment the command

`\nipsfinalcopy`

That should show a non-anonymized version of the document.